# SpaceChem: Can I quickly reset a reactor?

Tags: spacechem

I'd like to start anew with a reactor, scrapping all the current waldo programming. Can it be done? (I'm on a level with no top-level map, just a reactor. Not sure if that matters.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can click-drag to select the whole play field and hit Delete.

Sadly there is no Ctrl-A to select all, or that would be the way to go.

Comment: Additionally, you can toggle visibility of one of the red or blue layer if you only want to select/delete all of one layer